# Museum of televisions

Tags: where-on-earth, museums

Does anyone know a museum in which it is possible to see old TV equipment e.g. 405 line black and white TVs?  Ideally, some of them would be operating.

I am in the UK so museums in the UK would be most interesting but other answers are welcome.

As an example of the type of place that I am hoping for, here is a museum of telephones.  It is possible to call between them and see the exchange operating. [Avoncroft Museum](https://telephonesuk.org.uk/museums/avoncroft/)

I am not expecting to be able to visit at the moment due to Covid.  I am hoping that one day things return to normal and such visits become possible again.

Comment: In Fürth/Germany there's a museum dedicated to the inventions of Max Grundig. I haven't been there so I cannot say it's a correct answer to your question https://rundfunk-museum.de/

Comment: I have not been to: [National Science and Media Museum](https://www.scienceandmediamuseum.org.uk/) in Bradford (closed at the moment) which was originally called the [National Museum of Photography, Film and Television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Science_and_Media_Museum#National_Museum_of_Photography,_Film_and_Television).

Comment: Not specifically for televisions, but related are [The National Museum of Computing](https://bletchleypark.org.uk/visit-us/the-national-museum-of-computing) (Bletchley) and [The Centre for Computing History](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/) (Cambridge). They may or may not be open for reasons.

Comment: A collection of old TVs in Frankfurt, Germany https://sammlungen.museumsstiftung.de/fernsehgeraete/

Comment: @BernhardDöbler That sounds worth a visit when the world returns to normal.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not too far for me so definitely worth a visit.  Bletchley is great but not for this.

Comment: @Neusser Also worth checking.

Comment: I think we can have an answer with the definitive museums and an other with the wild shot ones. But am also happy to see all in the one answer, if so, list the good ones at the top of the 'iffy' ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A subject dear to me, as I started dismantling and repairing radios, B&W TVs, etc from the age of 12 in 1964. The most famous UK vintage TV museum is the British Vintage Wireless & Television Museum in Dulwich, London, (in Rosendale Road, where, incidentally, I went to school from ages 5 to 11). Regarding visits:

> The Museum has recently moved into Tier 2 [Covid restrictions].
>
> The Museum is therefore closed until further notice.
>
> We will not hold any events at the Museum until at least 2021
>
> Please check this website regularly for any change in this situation.

[BVW Museum](https://bvwm.org.uk/visit.htm)

[Video of the museum](https://www.safestore.co.uk/stuff-is-great/collections/vintage-radio-collector/?utm_source=SS&utm_medium=Outreach&utm_campaign=BL_SIG_20160510)

Here's something to whet your appetite

I can remember the smell these TVs gave off and I bet this place is full of it!

[image]

There is also this one but the website looks a bit old:

South West England Vintage Television Museum

[Web site](http://www.oldtechnology.net/tvmuseum/introduction.html)

if you want to read lots of forum discussions about restoring old UK and other radios, TVs, audio equipment, phones, computers, etc, this is a splendid forum:

[UK Vintage Radio Repair and Restoration Discussion Forum](https://www.vintage-radio.net/forum/)

Comment: That seems to be pretty much exectly what I wanted.  I also used to muck around with old TVs.  I was about the same age but it was the early 70s for me.  I don't accept immediately but it would take something special to beat this.  Covid is not an issue, there is no urgency and I can wait.

Comment: @badjohn -   If you haven't been to the Vintage Radio Forum, I strongly suggest it. It awoke a lot of memories for me. I used to repair colour TVs in the 70s and 80s and there are people discussing good old GEC 2040s and Decca Bradfords (my favourites) and all sorts!

Comment: I will.  I never played with colour sets, mostly cast off sets which were old even at the time.  It was a school electronics club but that really meant that the physics teacher allowed a few of us to play unsupervised in the lab at lunch time.  Health and safety - what's that?  240VAC never killed anyone.  (Last sentence is a joke, don't take it seriously.)

Comment: We're probably getting a bit off-topic, but the first (pre-war) B&W TVs derived the EHT for the picture tube direct from the mains via an oil-filled transformer, 2,000 volts at a hefty current capability, which definitely would kill anyone.

Comment: Very off topic for a travel forum.  I have worked on transformerless sets which just rectified the mains and had a live chassis but a mere few hundred volts.  We had a 240V:240V transformer which slightly reduced the danger.

Comment: Just about everything post-war up to the 1970s was 'live chassis', intially meaning the chassis was connected to one side of the mains. All well and good if the plug is 3-pin and wired correctly, and the socket wired the right way round, as the chassis is  always connected to neutral. A toddler was famously electrocuted by Dad's bodged job where he fitted legs to the TV using wood screws touching the chassis and the plug was wired wrongly. Later you could find (mainly colour) sets where the chassis was always at half mains potential, so the repair shops had to use 1:1 isolating transformers.

Comment: At last, I managed to visit this museum.  A little hard to find.  I went to the address and it appeared to be an ordinary residential house.  On closer inspection, I saw three door bells (it had been split into flats) and a tiny sign saying to use the passageway at the side to access the museum.  However, once I found it, it was marvellous.  A huge collection of radios and TVs, many of them working.  The staff were very enthusiastic and knowledgeable.  They outnumbered the visitors (just me) by 4 to 1.  If this subject interests you then you must visit.

Answer (score 6):

I think this question is good for a list of 'maybe' museums in a community wiki answer.

- Nederlands Instituut voor Beeld en Geluid, (Netherlands Insitude for Sound and Vision) [here is a link to their own website in Dutch,](https://museumtv.nl/museum/nederlands-instituut-voor-beeld-en-geluid/#) the Wikipedia page in [Dutch,](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nederlands_Instituut_voor_Beeld_en_Geluid) and in [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands_Institute_for_Sound_and_Vision).

  I remember from them being on TV that there might be some old televisions playing videos of old content, but could not see anything about it on any of the websites. The Dutch sites are worth checking out with an online translating service as the English language version is short. Most of what the museum concentrates on is Dutch language media content, from paper to digital formats, with a lot about TV.
- Norwegian Museum of Science and Technology (Norsk Teknisk Museum) in Oslo, Norway. Links to [English Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_Museum_of_Science_and_Technology) and [their own website](https://www.tekniskmuseum.no/oslo-vitensenters-installasjoner/88-welcome-to-the-norwegian-museum-of-science-and-technology).

  They have a large room near the entrance (start of the museum trail) which covers the history of television, including old televisions from various eras.
- Berlin, Germany

  - [Permanent Exhibition | Deutsche Kinemathek](https://www.deutsche-kinemathek.de/en/visit/exhibitions/permanent-exhibition)

    - I have never visited this museum
  - [Exhibitions - Stiftung Deutsches Technikmuseum Berlin](https://technikmuseum.berlin/en/exhibitions/)

    - A television used in 1936 (Olympic Games), with videos of some of the broadcasted programs are shown